# Thinktecture Identitiy Server and AngularJS SPA

Tags: angularjs, authentication, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3, thinktecture

Is there any js library that I can hook up into my AngularJS SPA that authenticates with Thinktecture Identity Server? AzureAD has adal.js to make it work with AzureAD, is there any I can use with Thinktecture ?

Comment: check this post: http://damienbod.com/2015/11/08/oauth2-implicit-flow-with-angular-and-asp-net-5-identity-server/

Comment: @leastprivilege - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823884/use-rs256-algorithm-to-sign-jwt